# redirect con variable Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, sweetalert

Estoy intentando redirigir a otra vista con laravel, y a esta vista quiero mandarle una variable llamada `update`. Lei la documentacion y lo hago tal como indica pero la variable no es reconocida.

```
return redirect('/Paciente/showAll')->with('update','success');
```

En la vista, tengo una funcion `@isset($update)` y si la variable existe salta una alerta `success si se modificó y fail si no lo hizo`

```
@isset($update)
    @if ($update == 'success')
    <script>
        window.onload = modificado;
        function modificado(){
            swal({
                icon: "success",
                text: "Modificado correctamente."
            });
        }
    </script> 
    @else
    <script>
        window.onload = modificado;
        function modificado(){
            swal({
                icon: "error",
                text: "Oops! A ocurrido un problema."
            });
        }
    </script> 
@endif
@endisset
```

Answer (score 0):

Para leer una variable que se le pasa junto a la redireccion hay que usar el metodo session('nombre_de_variable'), ya que como tal la variable `$update` no existe.

```
 //El primer if es para verificar si existe o no. Si no lo ponemos saltará la alerta siempre que se recargue. 

@if (session('update'))
//Este if ya nos verifica si la alerta es de success o de error
    @if (session('update') == 'success')
    <script>
        window.onload = modificado;
        function modificado(){
            swal({
                icon: "success",
                text: "Modificado correctamente."
            });
        }
    </script> 
    @else
    <script>
        window.onload = modificado;
        function modificado(){
            swal({
                icon: "error",
                text: "Oops! A ocurrido un problema."
            });
        }
    </script> 
    @endif
@endif
```